# How to redirect to the ?next=url instead of the success_url in a generic class based view in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'd like to know how to redirect to the ?next=url instead of the success_url in a generic class based view in django.

the view

```
class CategoryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = "categories/category_edit.html"
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'image')
    success_url = 'category_list'
```

in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'category_edit' category.id %}?next={% url 'another_url' %}">Add</a>
```

After updating the category, I want to be redirected to the nex value in the link instead of the success_url. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove success_url from the fields, then add get_success_url method to the class, for example:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    URL = self.request.GET.get('next')
    return URL
```

Comment: Very nice, I ended up using a default value for the view in case `next` was not set, it would operate normally:
`url = self.request.GET.get('next', self.success_url)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, thanks for your help.
I had to add these lines to the view and remove the success_url, as Andrey Borzenko said.

```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(CategoryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        next_page = self.request.GET.get('next')
        if next_page:
            context["next"] = next_page
        return context

   def get_success_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.POST.get('next')
        return redirect_to or reverse('default_redirection')
```